# Pass data from repeated form by a button

Tags: .net, codeigniter, model-view-controller, frontend, backend

I think it is a logic problem more than a code error.

I am working on Dotnet MVC.

In my view, I created a Button (addForm) to add forms dynamically as much as the user want. then, when the user finishes filling these forms; he can click submit button and data should be passed to an Action called Create and stored to the database.

I am able to create the addForm button and I am able to pass these data to the Action.

My issue is when I click the create submit it will pass this one form data to the action then I have to return a view.

I want to pass each form's data without redirecting the page or passing all forms' data to the Action with one click.

My action :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("TripId,TripDayNumber,TripDate,TimeFrom,TimeTo,ActivitiesId,PkgCityId")] TripDay tripDay)
    {
        // save data function  to DB
        return View(); // what should i return here 
    }
```

My view page:

```
            <div style="border:solid; border-color:black">
                                    <form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="agentPkGs">
                                        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                                       <div class="form-group">
                                            <label asp-for="TripDayNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                                            <input asp-for="TripDayNumber" class="form-control" />
                                            <span asp-validation-for="TripDayNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label asp-for="PkgCityId" class="control-label"></label>
                                            <select asp-for="PkgCityId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CityID"></select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label asp-for="TripDate" class="control-label"></label>
                                            <input asp-for="TripDate" class="form-control" />
                                            <span asp-validation-for="TripDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label asp-for="TimeFrom" class="control-label"></label>
                                            <input asp-for="TimeFrom" class="form-control" />
                                            <span asp-validation-for="TimeFrom" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label asp-for="TimeTo" class="control-label"></label>
                                            <input asp-for="TimeTo" class="form-control" />
                                            <span asp-validation-for="TimeTo" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label asp-for="ActivitiesId" class="control-label"></label>
                                            <select asp-for="ActivitiesId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ActivitiesId"></select>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                    </div>

          

                            </div>
                            <button onclick="addDiv()">Add Div</button>
                            <div id="myDiv"></div>

                            <script>
                                function addDiv() {
                                    var newDiv = $("<div>");
                                    newDiv.html(`
                                    <div style="border:solid; border-color:black">
                                 <form action="/agentPkGs/Create"  method="post">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <label for="PkgCityId">PkgCityId:</label>
                                    <select id="PkgCityId" name="PkgCityId" class="form-control">
                                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.CityID)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
                                        }
                                    
                                </select>


                                       
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <label for="TripDate">TripDate:</label>
                                          <input type="text" id="TripDate" name="TripDate" class="form-control" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <label for="TimeFrom">TimeFrom:</label>
                                          <input type="text" id="TimeFrom" name="TimeFrom" class="form-control" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <label for="TimeTo">TimeTo:</label>
                                          <input type="text" id="TimeTo" name="TimeTo" class="form-control" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <label for="ActivitiesId">ActivitiesId:</label>
                                          <select id="PkgCityId" name="PkgCityId" class="form-control">
                                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ActivitiesId)
                                            {
                                              <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
                                            }

                                               </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                        </div>
                                      </form>
                                      <button class='remove-button'>Remove Div</button>
                                    </div>
                                    `);
                                    $("#myDiv").append(newDiv);

                                    $(document).on("click", ".remove-button", function () {
                                        $(this).parent().remove();
                                    });
                                }
                            </script>
```

Comment: A form can work  with a submit , so when you click the create submit it will pass this one form data to the action.

Comment: i understand your point. But I want when the user clicks submit button (form data) will be passed to the controller but the page doesnt refresh or redirect to another view.  because the user alows to submit more than one form.